# Play framework + Netbeans 7, unable to expand project node!

Tags: netbeans, playframework, netbeans-7

I'm using Play 1.2.1, and have netbeansified a project, and opened the project in Netbeans 7. I am able to open and run the project, but the Projects sidebar won't allow me to open/expand the project node, so I can view the project folders.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known bug, a fix to neatbeans.py to is available here:

http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/334-netbeansify-folder-inclusionexclusion#ticket-334-3

The problem is a rouge entry in project.xml where it has tried to create a project directory for your source control folder (annoyed the hell out of me as well).

Comment: Thanks so much! This solved the issue, if only Google search came across this earlier! Now the day is wasted.